# If $a, b, c$ and $d$ are the four roots of the equation $\sin(2x) - m\cos(x) - n\sin(x) + r = 0$, prove that $a+b+c+d = (2p+1)π$ for some p ∈ Z

Tags: trigonometry

I have used the half angle formulae $\sin(x) = \frac{2\tan(\frac x2)}{1+\tan^2(\frac x2)}$ and $\cos(x) = \frac{1-\tan^2(\frac x2)}{1+\tan^2(\frac x2)}$ to turn this equation into a polynomial of degree $4$,

$(r+m)\tan^4(\frac{x}{2})-(2n+4)\tan^3(\frac{x}{2})+2r \tan^2(\frac{x}{2})+(4-2n) \tan(\frac{x}{2})+(r-m) = 0$

I'm unable to see what further action I need to take to prove that $a+b+c+d = (2p+1)π$

Comment: The question had to have been more specific than this. There are many cases where we won't obtain a solution at all (say $m=n=0$, $r=5$). Could you provide the extra details?

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta Hence the "if".

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta I have copied the question pretty much word for word from the book

Comment: @Calvin Lin oops, yeah right. Even so, what does the problem mean by "THE $4$ roots"? There are infinitely many of those. For example, if I take $m=n=r=0$, I get $x=\frac {n\pi}{2}$, so I can select roots $\pi, 2\pi, 3\pi, 4\pi$ and the condition of sum being odd multiple of $\pi$ won't be met.

Comment: @Asher2211 Thank you, I've edited the question to reflect that

Comment: @Asher2211 This question has been almost directly copied from a book, so I guess there are some other conditions for m, n and r that have been left out.

Comment: I think the question is missing some conditions on $m,n,r$. @Asher2211 Can you think of any counter example where $m,n,r \in \mathbb N$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: First, use tangent sum formula
$$
\tan(A+B) = \frac{\tan(A) + \tan(B)}{1- \tan(A) \tan(B)}
$$
to get a formula for $\tan(A+B+C+D)$.

Second, use Vieta's formulas to relate the coefficients of the polynomial you obtained to sums and products of its roots.

Third, plug these sums and products of roots into the formula for $\tan(A+B+C+D)$ to show that
$$
\tan(\frac{a+b+c+d}{2}) = \infty
$$